# comparing two delta tables and replacing values in databricks

Tags: python, pyspark

I Have 2 delta tables:
table1 has 10 columns (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)

[image]

and table 2 has 8 columns (c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)

[image]

i want to compare both tables with respect to column c and fecth all the values to table 1 if it matches.
and if column e has value 'closed' in table 2 then table 1 column b should be replaced with 'OK'

needed output like this

[image]

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should do that for you:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit

df_1 = spark.createDataFrame([(412, "NOT_OKAY", 123, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)], "a: int, b: string, c: int, d: string, e: string, f: string, g: string, h: string, i: string, j: string")
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame([(123, "abc", "Closed", "def", "ght", "drf", "erw", "rew")], "c: int, d: string, e: string, f: string, g: string, h: string, i: string, j: string")

df_1 \
    .join(df_2, "c") \
    .select([df_1['a'], df_1['b'], df_1['c'], df_2['d'], df_2['e'], df_2['f'], df_2['g'], df_2['h'], df_2['i'], df_2['j']]) \
    .withColumn("b", when(col("e") == "Closed", lit("OK")).otherwise(col("b"))) \
    .show()

+---+----+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|   b|  c|  d|     e|  f|  g|  h|  i|  j|
+---+----+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+---+
|412|OKAY|123|abc|Closed|def|ght|drf|erw|rew|
+---+----+---+---+------+---+---+---+---+---+
```